# how can i handle billion records effectivily

Tags: mysql, cassandra, query-optimization, accumulo

I have a performance issue,  while handling billion records using select query,I have a table as

```
CREATE TABLE `temp_content_closure2` (
  `parent_label` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_code_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `parent_depth` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `content_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `code_content` (`parent_code_id`,`content_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY KEY (parent_depth)
PARTITIONS 20 */ |
```

I used partition which will increase the performance by subdividing the table,but it is not usefull in my case,my sample select in this table

```
+----------------+----------------+--------------+------------+
| parent_label   | parent_code_id | parent_depth | content_id |
+----------------+----------------+--------------+------------+
|  Taxonomy |          20000 |            0 |        447 |
| Taxonomy |          20000 |            0 |       2286 |
|  Taxonomy |          20000 |            0 |       3422 |
| Taxonomy |          20000 |            0 |       5916 |
+----------------+----------------+--------------+------------+
```

Here the content_id will be unique in respect to the parent_dept,so i used parent_depth as a key for partitioning.In every depth i have 2577833 rows to handle ,so here partitioning is not useful,i got a idea from websites  to use archive storage engine but it will use full table scan and not use index in select ,basically 99% i use select query in this table and this table is going to increases its count every day.currently i am in mysql database which has 5.0.1 version.i got an idea about nosql database to use ,but is any way to handle in mysql ,if you are ssuggesting  nosql means which can i use cassandra or accumulo ?.

Comment: you should have an index on content_id at the very least

Comment: @FaddishWorm ,i added the composite primary key,its not usefull :(

Answer (score 0):

Add an index like this:

`ALTER TABLE table ADD INDEX content_id ('content_id')`

You can also add multiple indexes if you have more specific SELECT criteria which will also speed things up.

[Multiple and single indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155656/multiple-and-single-indexes)

Overall though, if you have a table like this thats growing so fast then you should probably be looking at restructuring your sql design.

Check out "Big Data" solutions as well.

Answer (score 0):

With that size and volume of data, you'd need to either setup a sharded-MySQL setup in a cluster of machines (Facebook and Twitter stored massive amounts of data on a sharded MySQL setup, so it is possible), or alternatively use a Big Table-based solution that natively distribute the data amongst nodes in various clusters- Cassandra and HBase are the most popular alternatives here. You must realize, a billion records on a single machine will hit almost every limit of the system- IO first, followed by memory, followed by CPU. It's simply not feasible.

If you do go the Big Table way, Cassandra will be the quickest to setup and test. However, if you anticipate map-reduce type analytic needs, then HBase is more tightly integrated with the Hadoop ecosystem, and should work out well. Performance-wise, they are both neck to neck, so take your pick.

Comment: Hi Nikhil,thanks for the replay,by the way i checked cassandra ,i wondered about its performance 1000 records insert per second in columnfamily,but there i cont able to do aggregation,mainly i am handling event audit so i need to group by and to use sum or count in data.for this cassandra did not have group by,sum function.i am not aware of HBase ,please say is this aggregation is possible in HBase if not how can i handle this?

Comment: In Cassandra, you will have to do any aggregation/grouping/filtering on the application side. Cassandra has client support for several languages (wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ClientOptions‎), so you could easily integrate your logic into a language of choice, and accomplish even more than what you would with SQL. HBase has similar restrictions, but offers an attractive option in the form of Phoenix (https://github.com/forcedotcom/phoenix), which effectively gives you a very familiar SQL-like layer over your HBase cluster, with support for many advanced operations.