# T-SQL Indices when using OR statement

Tags: t-sql, indexing

I've looked through several sources to get information on indices regarding AND statements, table joins, etc., but I've yet to find much useful information when there are OR statements present. That being said how would someone ideally handle creating indexes for a situation like the one here?

**Updated SQL Statement to not use `like`.**

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE table_name.field1 = 'criteria'
and (table_name.field2 = 1 or 
table_name.field3 = 0)
```

Obviously, I would want to create an index for `field1`. But whether I `include` fields 2 and 3 or handle this in another way, I'm not sure.  If this were a simple three part AND statement I would probably use `CREATE INDEX IND_index_name on table_name (field1, field2, field3)` but I have reason to believe this logic doesn't work the same way for OR statements. Based on the statement given, I can assume that field1 always needs to be evaluated first, but then I have multiple ways I could handle this. The potential solutions I am evaluating are listed below, but I'm not sure if there may yet be another better solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

1. `CREATE INDEX IND_index_name on table_name (field1) INCLUDING (field2, field3)`
2. `CREATE INDEX IND_index_name on table_name (field1, field2, field3)`
3. `CREATE INDEX IND_index_name1 on table_name (field1, field2)
   CREATE INDEX IND_index_name2 on table_name (field1, field3)`
4. `CREATE INDEX IND_index_name1 on table_name (field1)
   CREATE INDEX IND_index_name2 on table_name (field2)
   CREATE INDEX IND_index_name3 on table_name (field3)`

*As additional info, I do not have access to SQL Server Management Studio tools because I am using DBeaver. For the sake of this example let's assume it takes almost a full workday to run without indexes. The answers submitted here will be used to tackle a much larger more complex query where data from* `table_name` *would used in several subsequent queries that run after the query shown above.*

Comment: If you are designing the table you should only be concern  with primary key index. If you are tuning query performance, that depends  on the load, so it is better to do it against the real database. To do that you can run query plan. In latest versions of Microsoft SQL server the tool can provide hits to create index that respond to particular low performance querys

Comment: Thanks ByteArtisan. I would love to use the SQL Server query tuning, but I'm in an envrionment which uses DBeaver due to the variety of databases being used. The query I'm trying to tune takes 4 hours to complete because it is far more complex than the example shown. At this point I need to understand the best way to use indexes when there are OR statements involved so I can use that information to make appropriate changes.

Comment: In general, you should pick up the most granularity fields for index. If one is enough to narrow the search to a few records, that is sufficient. Using the indexed fields first on the query also is a good practice. 
Also, you should consider cost of each index. Small data fields, like integer, are fast and will consume less memory. Also, if you are writing the query, try to put the index fields first, not always the engine is smart enough to use them first. Hope it is enough.

Comment: In my scenario I'm looking at about 100,000,000 records and need to filter on a combination of 20+ fields (out of around 30) several times over to extract different datasets. I appreciate the consideration on the value of indices and how appropriate they may/may not be. However, I really just need to know how to work indexed fields appropriately with OR statements. The link here explains the logic to consider for AND statements, but I have not found anything like this in regards to OR statements. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155656/multiple-and-single-indexes

Comment: well, i think it is safe to say then when using or, the SQL engine as to search both fields always and merge the results. Also, with so many fields, using hint may help the engine choice. hits also are useful if statistics are not update. It is hard to give an solution, without observing the real data and do some experiences, so i can only provide some principles.

Comment: As I mentioned, the normal tools are not available to me since I am not using Managment Studio. Even if they were, I still need to understand how the indexes are applied to the query so I can set them up properly without spending weeks on testing due to the number of scenarios I would need to test and the amount of time each test would take. If you would like to provide an example index for the table listed and reasoning to support it, I would be grateful. Anything else is less helpful at the moment.

Comment: `field1 like '%criteria%'` means all rows have to be scanned anyway. the leading wildcard prevents an index seek.

Comment: Can you normalize your tables and use Clustered Index to sort them? You will have to join those but it would be Clustered index seek.

Comment: I can partially sort, but there are so many tables from the query results. The number of different combinations used make the indexing tedious. Maybe 75% of the subsequent tables created will reference one field (`field1` in this case) in particular, but others will ignore `field1` entirely. Due to the massive amount of data that comes back, applying the indexes properly could save hours of run time as opposed to using about 30 indexes in the current setup where many of them are duplicates (inherited code, not my doing). I'm just trying to account for the OR statements more than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

There is not one way to index OR

I would try 3 separate indexes